# ODS to LaTeX: use formatting from the ods file?

Tags: tables

There is a nice solution for importing tables from ods file, in the form of the `odsfile` package. For very simple, non-formatted tables it basically produces the same effect as the table in the ods. But for a little more complicated one, where there is background colour, bold, or say a subheader with merged cells, the default typesetting is rather unreadable and useless. Is there a way to - preferably automatically - read at least some formatting from the `ods` and feed it to `LaTeX`? If this is not really possible, is there a way to tell it which rows should count as a "subheader" and add some extra formatting to that, and which as a regular line?

This is the include I use:

```
\includespread[template=booktabs,file=test.ods,sheet=test]
```

[This](http://fbence.web.elte.hu/test.ods) would be an example of an ods I have in mind.

**EDIT**

Using version `2015/10/15 v0.7` from github and the following mwe:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{odsfile,booktabs}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\newcommand{\Lpagenumber}{\bgroup
  \dimendef\margin=0
  \ifodd\value{page}\margin=\oddsidemargin
  \else\margin=\evensidemargin
  \fi
  \raisebox{\dimexpr 0.5in - 0.5\paperheight}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \rlap{\hspace{\dimexpr \margin+\textheight+\footskip}\rotatebox{90}{\thepage}}}
\egroup}


\listfiles
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\includespread[template=booktabs,file=test.ods,sheet=test]
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\AddThispageHook{\Lpagenumber}%
\end{landscape}

\includespread[template=booktabs,file=test.ods,sheet=test]
\end{document}
```

Produces [this](http://fbence.web.elte.hu/mwe.pdf) pdf. The bolding is not preserved from the ods and I also get a seemingly unnecessary new page.

Comment: you can try the development version from Github, I've fixed there some things regarding merged cells recently. I think bold and other basic text styles should work, more complicated styles like background colors or borders doesn't. I can't look at it now, maybe later this weekend, hopefully.

Comment: I tried using the package from git and also tried to look at the code, but I realized I really don't know enough LaTeX and Lua to understand it :( but it didn't work out :( But this package is really a great idea :)